# writing "<" and ">" to a xml file instead of &lt; and &gt; in java

Tags: java, xml

i have to write a few lines to a xml file which should contain < and > symbols as part of value of a tag.
i am setting them in a string that has some text along with  < and > symbols , and after marshalling through jaxb the xml which gets created has ;lt; and ;gt; instead of the < and > symbols. i tried using escape characters and ascii 60 and 62 values to get them as < and > but didn't work. Can anyone suggest some solution for this.

Comment: have a look at CDATA wrapping

Comment: It's not clear to me. Are you trying to write invalid XML ?

Answer (score 5):

> ...the xml which gets created has ;lt; and ;gt; instead of the `<` and `>` symbols...

I assume you mean `&lt;` and `&gt;`. That's correct. That's how you write `<` and `>` in XML text (although you're allowed to use `>` literally as well, see below). They're called named character entities.

This:

```
<foo>6 &lt; 7</foo>
```

...defines an XML element with the content "6 < 7" in it.

This:

```
<foo>6 < 7</foo>
```

is invalid XML that will not parse.

An alternative to character entities is to use a CDATA section:

```
<foo><![CDATA[6 < 7]]></foo>
```

Everything between the `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` is treated as raw text, not XML. But note that the resulting XML DOM is slightly different. The `foo` element's value is a CDATA section, which in turn has the value of `"6 < 7"`. So it's less direct. When you use the character entity, `foo`'s value is `"6 < 7"` (without any intervening bit).

Technically, you can write `>` in the XML literally if you like. These two lines define exactly the same thing:

```
<foo>7 &gt; 6</foo>
<foo>7 > 6</foo>
```

Both are valid, and the resulting data when you parse it is exactly the same. But you normally see the first rather than the second.

---

Side note: `&` must also be written using a character entity, since `&` is what character entities start with. So to have an `&` in text, you use `&amp;`:

```
<foo>Jones &amp; Cooper Co.</foo>
```

Comment: but actually i wanted in the xml to show up like <foo>6 < 7 </foo>
So how can i achieve it.

Comment: @TheUser: You cannot. As I said, it's invalid XML. But again, the *value* of the `<foo>6 &lt; 7</foo>` element is `6 < 7`. The `&lt;` is a special thing, called a character entity, that represents the `<` character.

Comment: If it showed up as `<foo>6 < 7 </foo>` then it wouldn't be XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
<xml>
 <![CDATA[
   <data>sdsjddjdsdjs</data>
 ]]>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

if we suppose that el is your element then:
from lxml import etree

```
el.text = etree.CDATA('a string')
```

ref: http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.CDATA-class.html