# Xml Tags get wrong encoded

Tags: c#, xml, encoding

I'm trying to write a list of objects to valid xml. My code looks basicly like this:

```
public class Person
        {
            public string First { get; set; }
            public string Last { get; set; }
        }

List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

XElement elements = new XElement("People",
                        from p in people
                        select new XElement("Person",
                            new XElement("First", p.First),
                            new XElement("Last", p.Last)));

string output = elements.ToString();
```

Unfortunately output when written to a file looks like this:

> ```
> &lt;People&gt;
>   &lt;Person&gt;
>     &lt;First&gt;Tom&lt;/First&gt;
>     &lt;Last&gt;Hanks&lt;/Last&gt;
>   &lt;/Person&gt;
> &lt;/People&gt;
> ```

```
XDeclaration declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes");
XProcessingInstruction procInstruction = new XProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl'");
XElement root = new XElement("Store");
XDocument settingsFile = new XDocument(declaration, procInstruction, root);

                foreach (string key in persistentSettings.Keys)
                {
                    string value = persistentSettings[key];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    {
                        XElement setting = new XElement("Setting", new XAttribute("Name", key));
                        setting.Value = value;
                        root.Add(setting);
                    }
                }
                settingsFile.Save(SettingsFileName);
```

What is that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503725/replace-lt-and-gt-with-and-in-sql-server

Comment: just replacing can't be the right solution I guess

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908251/writing-and-to-a-xml-file-instead-of-lt-and-gt-in-java

Comment: You must be double-serializing your XML somewhere.  I.e. you are serializing your `XElement` to a string, then serializing that string to XML a second time.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/5Si0Hp for a demo.  The solution is to not do that.  Instead let your framework serialize for you.  But your question doesn't show the framework you are using, so there isn't enough information to answer the question.

Comment: you are right I just added the code for the writeing to file. the line `root.Add(...)` destroys (double-serializes) it.

Comment: but still no idea how to fix that

Comment: actually assigning value to setting.Value already causes the problem

Comment: I'm confused as you have one code block with puts values in XElements and then does a .ToString() and another code block which saves an XDocument. Can you clarify?

Comment: maybe that causes the problem?

Comment: I think the problem might be that I'm doing xlement tostring and then set this as value for an xelement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the parse function in the *Constructor* of `xElement`

```
XElement setting 
   = new XElement("Setting", new XAttribute("Name", key), XElement.Parse(value));
```

instead of

```
XElement setting = new XElement("Setting", new XAttribute("Name", key));
setting.Value = value;
```